# Implementing Drag and Drop with QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, treeview

I am trying to implement drag and drop for a TreeView using a model based off of QAbstractItemModel, taken from [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html).

As instructed [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views) I have enabled my TreeView for drag&drop like so:

```
view->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
view->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
view->setDragEnabled(true);
view->setAcceptDrops(true);
view->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
```

I have set the appropriate flags in my model as well:

```
Qt::ItemFlags TreeModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return 0;

    return Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt::ItemIsEditable | QAbstractItemModel::flags(index);
}
```

And reimplemented QAbstractItemModel::supportedDropActions()

```
Qt::DropActions TreeModel::supportedDropActions() const
{
    return Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction;
}
```

The result is that when I drop one row on top of another, the latter gets a new child row and the original row is not deleted. However, all I want is to be able to switch the ordering of my top-level rows.

Perhaps my [model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html) is unsuitable? I have found [this article](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/dnd.html) in the documentation, but it seems more complex than what I need.

Edit: I have now implemented `DropMimeData()` as follow, still no luck though.

```
bool TreeModel::dropMimeData(const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent){

    if(!canDropMimeData(data, action, row, column, parent))
            return false;

    if (action == Qt::IgnoreAction)
        return true;

    int beginRow;

    if (row != -1)
        beginRow = row;
    else if (parent.isValid())
        beginRow = parent.row();
    else
        beginRow = rowCount(QModelIndex());

    removeRow(row, parent);
    insertRow(beginRow, parent);
    setData(parent.child(beginRow, 0), data);

    return true;

}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dropMimeData): you need to implement `dropMimeData` method in your model. Here's [one example](https://github.com/d1vanov/PyQt5-reorderable-list-model) of a model reorderable via drag-n-drop, although it is a list model, not a tree one and the code is in PyQt5.

Comment: @Dmitry i've reimplemented it. I can't test whether it works yet because I can't actually drop anything between rows. The `row` given to `dropMimeData` is always `-1` (means item is dropped on parent), and when i'm attempting to drop it only puts a box around the row i'm hovering over, not between rows. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: What is the value of the drop `action` given to `dropMimeData`? It is `copy` or `move`?

Comment: the value is `move`

Comment: It seems my model is still trying to add the dropped item as a child. I found that the `row` and `column` passed to `dropMimeData` are both `-1`. While the `parent`'s `QModelIndex`, points to the place where the item has been dropped.

Comment: Yes, your model still inserts the dropped item as a child of the parent. I believe for reordering you need to handle it differently: insert into the grand parent i.e. `QModelIndex grandParent = parent.parent(); insertRow(beginRow, grandParent);` also you probably don't need to call `removeRow` on your own, Qt should remove the dropped item from its original position on its own after `dropMimeData` method returns.

Comment: Good point. Now all I'm doing is inserting a brand new row into where the item is dropped. The old row isn't deleted and the new one contains no data. Do I need to reimplement any other functions so that the new row contains the data of the old one?

Comment: Well, your model needs to implement `insertRows` and `removeRows` as both would be involved in the sequence of events.

Comment: i've already reimplemented those. What I'm wondering is how I set the data of the inserted row? How is the data from the original row translated to QMimeData and how can i get the data back upon insertions. I can't just do `setData(QMimeData)` can I?

Comment: Hmm, good question. It won't be simple unless you can decode the information about the dragged item from the mime data. I don't know how the Qt's default encoding works but you can implement your own `mimeData` method and return the information about parent/row/column of the dragged items.

Comment: I was learning this as well lately. This is a great example how u can reimplement some of the functionality... https://github.com/jimmykuu/PyQt-PySide-Cookbook/blob/master/tree/drop_indicator.md hope it helps!